# How to feed a group of handlers with value fetched from Db in servant?

Tags: haskell, servant

I'm using servant with JWT authentication. I'm trying to fetch authenticated user and pass it to handlers not to have to repeat same logic in each handler.

With a single argument function it works like a charm:

```
listMeters :: Entity User -> Handler [Meter]
protected :: Servant.Auth.Server.AuthResult Token -> Server Protected
protected (Servant.Auth.Server.Authenticated email) = do
  user <- getUser email
  listMeters user
```

On the other hand when I try to do the same with function that takes two parameters:

```
addMeter :: Entity User -> Meter -> Handler Meter
protected :: Servant.Auth.Server.AuthResult Token -> Server Protected
protected (Servant.Auth.Server.Authenticated email) = do
  user <- getUser email
  addMeter user
```

It throws compilation error:

```
/usr/src/app/src/Handlers.hs:57:3: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Handler b0’ with ‘Meter -> Handler Meter’
      Expected type: Server Protected
        Actual type: Handler b0
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: user <- getUser email
      In the expression:
        do user <- getUser email
           addMeter user
      In an equation for ‘protected’:
          protected (Authenticated email)
            = do user <- getUser email
                 addMeter user
   |
57 |   user <- getUser email
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/usr/src/app/src/Handlers.hs:64:3: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Handler b0’
                  with actual type ‘Meter -> Handler Meter’
    • Probable cause: ‘addMeter’ is applied to too few arguments
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: addMeter user
      In the expression:
        do user <- getUser email
           addMeter user
      In an equation for ‘protected’:
          protected (Authenticated email)
            = do user <- getUser email
                 addMeter user
   |
64 |   addMeter user
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Function fetching users from db:

```
getUser :: Token -> Handler (Entity User)
getUser email = do
  userEntity <- liftIO $ runSql $ getBy $ UniqueEmail email
  case userEntity of
        Nothing -> throwError err401
        Just user -> return user
```

Why does the first example work and the other doesn't? How to resolve such a case properly in servant?

Comment: Hello! Have you checked out [this tutorial page](https://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/Authentication.html#generalized-authentication) or say [this cookbook recipe](https://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cookbook/jwt-and-basic-auth/JWTAndBasicAuth.html#authentication) ? If you use servant's mechanism for specifying your authentication scheme, servant will actually extract and pass that `Entity User` value around for you, as shown in the examples. Let me know here if that's not clear enough.

Comment: Hi @AlpMestanogullari thank you for response. I guess generalized authentication is the way to go then. In fact I tried to use regular jwt with an additional step of fetching user from db so I wondered if there is any easier method to accomplish this. Furthermore I can imagine such a way of executing certain code for a group of handlers could be helpful in other cases too so I wondered if it is possible in servant

Comment: Note that there's also a [servant-auth](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-auth) package which provides JWT out of the box, but still works on the same principle of declaring the auth-protection and having some user data be given to all the handlers that are protected behind authentication.

Comment: Sorry I didnt clearly state that I'm using servant-auth and it's JWT already. To make it clear: authentication itself works. I just wanted to pass Entity User to handlers instead of Token but I dunno how to accomplish this (generalized authentication seems a bit too much for such a simple modification) since it needs to run in specific monad to access database and throw exceptions (as shown in getUser function). That's why I generalized my question since it's not strictly related to authentication rather to  passing db objects to handlers at a higher level.

Comment: Also please note I'm aware that there are some workarounds to fix it. I just asked out of curiosity if it is possible in servant to define behaviour common for group of handlers. Alternatively I thought if I can use FromJWT to fetch user from db but it is unfortunately underdocumented and I didnt find any example of such

Comment: Oh I see! It feels like this is a terrible place to discuss your problem. I'm not sure I understand it 100% yet so I don't feel like posting a proper answer that's actually full of questions, but those comments just feel so tiny and inappropriate for discussing things. Would you mind opening an issue on servant's issue tracker? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure, will do. Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular problem creating a custom instance of IsAuth seems to be the best solution. There seem to be no official/idiomatic way though.

I've solved the problem by doing:

```
data UserCookie

extractUser userId = (maybe mzero (return . Entity userId)) =<< fetch
  where
    fetch = liftIO $ runSql $ get userId

instance IsAuth UserCookie (Entity User) where
  type AuthArgs UserCookie = '[CookieSettings, JWTSettings]
  runAuth _ _ = \c jwt -> extractUser =<< cookieAuthCheck c jwt
```

This link might also be helpful: https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant-auth/issues/73